# Maven, Integrating POM with SOAP UI test case with the main pom

Tags: maven-3

I have a POM with SOAP UI test case. Please let me know how can I integrate with the main POM so that test case are executed before deployment.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Was able to call using the project aggregation methodology.